# Android: can i update automatically a GalleryView?

Tags: android, dynamic, android-gallery

I have a gallery that shows images from the sdcard; i would like to automatically populate it when the user adds new images in sdcard.
Is there a way to do it?

Actually i make a loop in the filesystem to select image names; i don't use the ContentProvider because i've seen that if the user does not go to the Gallery app, thumbnails are not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler/Thread to run it automatically